# Why are there so many non-denominated amounts in the result of output_histogram?

Tags: blockchain, available-outputs

As of block height 1169864, the command `output_histogram` from the daemon gives me the following result:

```
output_histogram
3  0.000929635403
3  0.003483702322
3  0.003483172627
3  14.170000000000
3  14.110000000000
3  14.060000000000
3  14.050000000000
...
2224  0.000510000000
2229  0.000970000000
2232  0.000420000000
2258  0.000410000000
2266  0.000860000000
2270  0.000750000000
3548  2000.000000000000
5022  800.000000000000
5025  700.000000000000
5952  600.000000000000
...
905471  10.000000000000
907961  0.300000000000
939427  0.100000000000
1071303  0.500000000000
1204368  0.200000000000
```

Why are the amounts with instances of 2270 or less not in denomination?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old dust that has never been swept. Denominations and other enhancements weren't around when Monero launched.